# Linux Mint: Network connection only several seconds after boot

Tags: linux, networking, boot, linux-mint, systemd

I have the following problem:

After the boot process, it takes a few seconds until a network is available. This means, for example, that network drives cannot be mounted or certain websites are only loaded 5-10 seconds after booting because there was no network connection beforehand.
The error does not occur with a freshly installed Linux Mint and Windows. Therefore, it is not a hardware or network error, but must be due to the operating system used.

How can I find out why it takes so long until my PC has a network connection, or where can I get more information about this error?

Here is some more information about the used system

```
~ sudo inxi -Fxxxrz
System:
  Kernel: 6.6.0-060600rc5-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.8.4 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: muffin dm: LightDM 1.30.0
    Distro: Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: N/A
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: TUF GAMING X670E-PLUS v: Rev 1.xx serial: <filter>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1813 date: 10/13/2023
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: kernel
    pcie: speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: e000 bus-ID: 0a:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8125
    class-ID: 0200
  IF: eno1 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: virbr0 state: down mac: <filter>


~ sudo systemd-analyze blame                              
2min 81ms systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
   6.294s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
   1.173s smartmontools.service
    653ms snapd.service
```

If my question is a duplicate, I apologize. I unfortunately don't have any clues as to what exactly I should google in this case.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You may try to add the option `_netdev` in fstab, to delay the mount until the network is available.

Comment: I have already tried this, but it didn't work for me. 
I'm actually looking for the cause of the problem and wouldn't want to fix all the symptoms.

Comment: There's at least one way / package to check what's taking so long at boot, I'd search for something like boot times or boot delays or boot chart...

Answer (score 1):

The aforementioned _netdev will certainly help with any mounted remote shares. But you also may need to debug what the network delay itself is caused by.

My first thought is how are you connecting? Is there a dhcp issue? Try setting a static ip address. Check your dhcp service for address exhaustion from too small a range etc. DHCP is normally pretty instant but it could be a problem.
Also are you sure it actually isn't connected, check for DNS issues - try pinging some public ip addresses like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 etc.

Have a look in your logs (eg: less /var/log/syslog  ) and see if there is anything else showing errors relating to network/dhcp/name resolution.

Lastly, start with the physical layer - network cables being fault can cause some strange issues. Test/swap cables at your switch/router etc.